# How to deal with nested functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, call, invoke

It might be a beginner question but I'm facing with the next situation:

```
$(function f() {

  function test2() {
    //.....
  }

  function GetData() {
    //.....
  }    
  function update() {
    test2();
    GetData();
    //...
  }//end update

  update();

});//end f()

function stop() {
  clearInterval(multipleCalls);
}

function start() {
  multipleCalls=null; //this is a global variable
  setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
```

The stop function stops a graphic when a button is pressed and everything works fine. The start function should restart a graphic  when a button is pressed. My guess is that the update function is not well invoked in start function. How could I do so everything to work fine?

Comment: Why is `update()` calling itself?

Comment: Doesn't quite directly answer the question, but for future reference, I was always taught that nested functions should be of the form var funcname = function() { ... }. It'll work either way, but it's more organized and looks cleaner.

Comment: atleast indentation should be done

Comment: You're guessing right, `update` is hidden in `f` and isn't accessible from outside.

Comment: What is `GetData` and how is it relevant to your issue? What about `test2`? And `update`? Why is `multipleCalls` never set? Why is there `multiplecalls` and `multipleCalls`? Please check what is a [mcve].

Comment: @Kyll test2 and  GetData function does something and are called in update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have currently commented out the `}` that closes the `update` function, so the line that says `end f` doesn't in fact end `f()`. In its present state, your code would not execute. (I note that someone else edited your code after which this remark is no longer valid; I don't know if the edit is closer to your actual code, or if it did in fact obscure a real error)
- You're referring to both `multiplecalls` and `multipleCalls`. Note that javascript is case sensitive.
- You're clearing `multipleCalls` but never setting it to anything but `null`. Did you intend to write `multipleCalls = setTimeout(update, 1000)` ?
- `start`, being placed outside of `f`, won't have access to `update`. Either define `update` and the functions it is dependent upon outside of `f()`, or make it globally accessible, i.e.

  ```
  window.update = function() { ... }
  ```

  Which you'd then be able to access as `setTimeout(window.update, 1000);`

Comment: Hedlung It was my mistake with multipleCalls.

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping issue. The `update` is only known *within* the `f`.

You are trying to call it from outside `f` in `start`. The only way to achieve this is to either expose `function update` to the same scope as where `start` is, or bring `start` to the same scope as `update`.

The first option is easiest (and ugliest):

```
function update() {
  //...
}
//  assign it to the global scope (window is the global scope for browsers)
window.update = update;
```

Now `update` is available from `starts.

The more appropriate approach would be to define your handlers (which call `start` and `stop` within the scope of `f`, for example

```
$(function f() {
  //.. everything there now

  $('.start').on('click', function(e) {
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
  });
});
```

Working example

```js
$(function f() {
  var timer;  //  no need to be 'global'
  
  function update() {
     $('.result').text(new Date() + ' GetData();');
  }

  $('.start').on('click', function() {
    //  always clear a timer before setting it
    clearTimeout(timer);
    //  and always set a timer variable, so it can be cancelled
    timer = setTimeout(update, 1000);
  });

  $('.stop').on('click', function() {
    //  cancel the timer
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class=start>start</button>
<button class=stop>stop</button>

<div class=result>..</div>
```

Comment: Rogier, many thanks for your examples. I have another type of button so things are a little bit different.

Comment: Well, do the examples help you understand the actual problem and possible solutions? If not, tell me how we can clarify it further.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
window.update = function update() {...}
```

and then:

```
setTimeout(window.update, 1000);
```